# How to edit image from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my aspx:

```
<td>
   <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" />  
</td>
```

cs:

This is for insertion:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure1", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
try
{
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
     fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));                   
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", "Images/" + filename);
     com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

After inserted all the details, it shows like [***this***](http://s14.postimg.org/6ob8pbtm9/untitled.jpg):

And this is for edit from gridview:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
     if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
     {
         GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
         int index = gr.RowIndex; 
         hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString(); 
         Textid.Text = gr.Cells[0].Text;
         Textusername.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
         Textclass.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
         Textsection.Text = gr.Cells[3].Text;
         Textaddress.Text = gr.Cells[4].Text;               
     }
}
```

When I edit particular row from `GridView`, it will edit expect the image.

So the image is not editable. May I know how to edit the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

First add 2 hidden (hd_gv, hd_update) field one next to your image control  inside the Gridview control and other in the form, and set the hidden field value with the image src.

Now on Gridview_RowCommand  **get** the src and **set** the hd_update hidden field value, so your code looks like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
    if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
    {
    
       GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        HiddenField imgSRC = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hd_gv");
        hd_update.Value=imgSRC.Value;
    }
```

Now on your update function first check if the Fileupload control has any file if yes, then upload the file and update the image src with newly upload file else set the hd_update (hidden field) value.

Update Code look like this  on button click

```
string Filename = hd_update.Value; // "HIDDEN_FIELD_IMAGE_SRC";
if (fileupload.HasFile)
{
     //code to upload and set Filename variable with new file
     Filename="NEW FILE NAME";
}
```